# Is it possible to group (cascade) different exes into one taskbar item?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, taskbar

I have two different exes, one is C++ and the other is in C# form, both are coming as different taskbar entities. I would like to know is it possible to add the second Exe (C# form) taskbar item to first one's.

Please note that these two are having different icons, but I want to group (vertical cascade) both into one group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are the author of both programs, yes, it is possible by setting the Application Model Id.

In short, you need to call the SetCurrentProcessExplicitAppUserModelID Win32 API Function with an identical string AppId.

This excellent blog entry on the topic has more:

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20120820-00/?p=6813

Note that you will need to use a common application Id in both cases. The linked article focuses on the C++ aspect. You'll need to find a .NET exposure for the equivalent or P/Invoke it.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: Thank you for the pointer to the meta topic, @manetsus. I'll edit to point to the key API's.